# how to covert a character to numeric variable in SAS

Tags: sas, character, numeric

I am trying to convert the variable "MAGE" from character to numeric in SAS

I tried new_MAGE = input(MAGE, informat.);

and received and an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an actual informat specification, not the string **informat.**.

For most values try the normal numeric informat.  The INPUT() function does not care if you use a width on the informat specification that is larger than the length of the string being read.  So just use:

```
data want;
  set have;
  new_MAGE = input(MAGE, 32.);
run;
```

If the values in MAGE have thousands separators then you might want to use the COMMA informat instead.

```
data want;
  set have;
  new_MAGE = input(MAGE, comma32.);
run;
```